# All valid double stop shapes

Tags: guitar

Self-learning guitar. Just found out about double stops. I wonder if there is any rule that restricts which notes exactly you can combine in a double stop? Or, to put it in other words, which are allowed (most common) shapes for a good double stop.

Comment: What do you mean by shape? Left hand? Right hand? Chord shape? Also nothing is just outright not allowed, even the ones that can sound dissonant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Double stops are just two-note chords. There's nothing otherwise special about them. And I think the only reason the term—which was originally meant for orchestral strings where it requires special technique to bow 2 strings
 at a time—gets used is because nobody has a better term for two-note chords. There's the term "dyad" but it doesn't get used much.

It could be *any* two notes, but some notes will sound better or worse depending on context just like other chords. So I'd recommend learning some of the basic theory of harmony. If you haven't already, learn:

1. Learn [how the major scale is constructed](https://www.musictheory.net/lessons/21).
2. [Learn about intervals](https://www.musictheory.net/lessons/30) and which ones stay within the major scale.
3. Learn [how chords are constructed](https://www.musictheory.net/lessons/40) from the major scale [by stacking 3rds](https://www.musictheory.net/lessons/43) and what intervals they contain.

Armed with that knowledge you'll be able to decide things like "ok I'm on a minor chord here so I can make a double stop from this interval that exists within this minor chord".

Answer (score 1):

Double stops is the term for *any* two notes played together. Yes, even a power chord ! Notes one fret, or two frets apart will most often sound bad, but a nice way to explore is to play a major scale purely on the second string, say, starting on 1st fret. It'll be C major. Notice that the 3rd note you play is the same as top string open, but carry on up to 13th fret anyway. Now play all notes from the third note up the top string. Next is to play two notes , 2nd and top strings, so it'll be 1+3, then 2+4, 3+5 (scale note numbers!) etc.

You asked about 'rules' - well, those double stops work in key C, and it makes sense that any notes in your double stops belong to the key you're playing in, generally. Those are called **thirds**, but a really nice sounding double stop is the **sixth**, but on guitar, you'll need to play them on 3rd and 1st strings - same sort of idea as previous. For both, you'll see a pattern - the former uses notes one fret/two frets apart, whereas the latter uses notes on same fret/one fret apart.

Answer (score 1):

most common are octaves, major triads and fifths and 4ths, unisons are used often, but surely there are no rules except common sense to play what is natural on guitar,  for the piano and violin you can find tutorials on double notes since 15th century. Chopin 6th etude and many other piano fragments and entire works are based upon double notes and Balakiriev`a Islamey also, in Paganini`s caprices for violin you can find double notes in all combinations which 4 strings can hold.

Answer (score 0):

I worked up charts on guitar neck diagrams for both the up the neck and across the neck double stop fingering patterns which can be applied to different keys by starting on desired roots and moving up or across from that point. Also I took a cue from the CAGED system and charted from different positions which are also moveable. After learning and practicing I have developed my own favorite fingering patterns. I did this for guitar, for thirds and again for fifths, but I could do it for any given interval. I also feel it could be adapted to any chord capable instrument.